# window on load error check javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to check child window loaded or blocked by popup blocker

I am doing this way but not getting error on child window blocked by popup blocker

**parent.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var check_var = false;
document.onclick=function(){
        var myWindow = window.open("child.html", "", "display=none, visible=none, width=1px, height=1px,left=100000px, top=100000px");
        myWindow.onload = function() { 
                alert(check_var); 
        };
        myWindow.onerror = function() { 
                alert('error'); // does not show errror
        };
}
</script>
```

**child.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
opener.check_var = true;
window.close();
</script>
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this, jQuery solution is preferable.

Thanks

Comment: instead of `var check_var = false;`; can you please try like `window.check_var = false;`

Comment: @vijayP didn't work this way either

Comment: Is this child window, an iFrame?

Comment: @Rajesh no a popup window

Comment: Why should the `onerror` handler fire?

Comment: @AxelAmthor I am just trying don't know it will fire or not

Comment: Sorry, but in what browser do you test? `windowObjectReference` is null if window open is failed by any reason, including popups blocks.

Comment: I think @MihailsButorins is correct. Instead to trying to attach callback functions to the window (after it has already been created), have you tried using `if(myWindow) alert(check_var); else alert('error');` after opening the new window?

Comment: @AndrewTomlinson it alerts `check_var` value even if popup is blocked